# My mysqli_connect() doesn't return anything. no result, no error, no object

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Added the code to connect to my mysql db. Installed the proper extension mysqli in php.ini.
But I'm not getting any success or error back.

```
$host="localhost";
$port=3306;
$socket="";
$user="root";
$password="";
$dbname="deve";

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket);
if(mysqli_connect_error()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

I've tried var_dump to get more info, with no luck, nothing came back. just blank page.

```
var_dump($con->info);

var_dump($con->client_info);
var_dump($con->client_version);
var_dump($con->info);
```

Comment: It either returns something or throws an exception. Do you have PHP error reporting enabled?

Comment: I changed the link pinned at the top of your question, to the answer that, I hope, explain this issue in detail. If you still have any questions, feel free to ask